# Creating Google Calendar from Google Sheets not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I tried to write a code that create a event in Google Calendar with information from a Google Sheet. When I try to run in my sheet is returned that it was succefull but nothing happens in the calendar. What I'm doing wrong? [Image from the sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9hfu.png)

```
function scheduleAluguel() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("F7").getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

  var alugueis = spreadsheet.getRange("D2:F5");

  for (x = 0; x < alugueis.length; x++) {
    var venda = alugueis[x];

    var startTime = venda[0];
    var endTime = venda[1];
    var name = venda[2];

    eventCal.createEvent(name, startTime, endTime);    
  }
}

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Sync com calendário')
    .addItem('Agendar agora', 'scheduleAluguel')
    .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: "_nothing happens in the sheet_" - I assume you mean nothing happens in the Calendar, right?

Comment: That is right, my bad

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line:

```
var alugueis = spreadsheet.getRange("D2:F5");
```

to this:

```
var alugueis = spreadsheet.getRange("D2:F4").getValues();
```

---

**Additional Notes**

The `getRange()` function returns a [`Range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) object.

You need the [values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()), which are in the format of a 2-dimensional data array.

This array is what your code is expecting to iterate over, in its `for` loop.

---

Caveat:

My default date format is different from the one you show in your screenshot, but I assume the date/time data you are using is valid for your locale.

Comment: I added 'getValues();' and did some simulations. 
'eventCal.createEvent(name, startTime, endTime);' seems to work outside the loop, the information gets to the calendar

Answer (score 0):

```
function scheduleAluguel() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("F7").getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

  var alugueis = spreadsheet.getRange("D2:F5").getValues();//missing get Values

  for (x = 0; x < alugueis.length; x++) {
    var venda = alugueis[x];

    var startTime = venda[0];
    var endTime = venda[1];
    var name = venda[2];

    eventCal.createEvent(name, startTime, endTime);    
  }
}
```

Data Sheet Data:

|  |  |  | HDR1 | HDR2 | HDR3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | 6/2/2021 0:00:00 | 6/3/2021 0:00:00 | Title1 |
|  |  |  | 6/3/2021 0:00:00 | 6/4/2021 0:00:00 | Title2 |
|  |  |  | 6/4/2021 0:00:00 | 6/5/2021 0:00:00 | Title3 |
|  |  |  | 6/5/2021 0:00:00 | 6/6/2021 0:00:00 | Title4 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  | Redacted |